# (Fast Question) How do i call this equality

Tags: geometry

First of all, sorry for the inconvenient, cz i can't use my source image fiture bcz of some troubles. But, i believe all of you smarter than me to understand this, so i think it's not a big deal to using the ASCII.

Well, suppose i have $4$ identical rectangles that are congruent. Each rectangle has sides of one unit.

And i want to arrange my rectangles such that they have these forms :

1) Rectangles form like a window. New shape : (Big rectangle that has the same sides which is $2$ units.

```
+---+---+
|   |   |
+---+---+
|   |   |
+---+---+
```

We have :

Area : $4$

Perimeter : $10$

2) Rectangles form horizontal shape which contains $4$ rectangles horizontally

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Area : $4$

Perimeter: $8$

3) Rectangles form the upside letter T.

```
    +---+
    |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Area : $4$

Perimeter : $8$

All of them have the same area, but different perimeter. But in case ($2$) and ($3$) we have the shapes which have the same area and the perimeter.

How do i call the relation between ($2$) and ($3$)? They have different shape, but have the same area and perimeter?

If they are have the same shape then they are congruent right? But what about this case? How do i call this relation?

I hope you're not confuse with my question.

Btw, i can't draw it correctly, becuase of the left aligning system on this section. And please to tell me if you don't understand what i mean, instead of just downvoting.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a special name for shapes having the same area and perimeter.

Comment: You would need to create a term yourself. Equable is already used for shapes where the area is equal to the perimeter. Perhaps Congrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two or more geometric shapes with the same perimiter may be referred to as: **isoperimetric**.

Ref:
[Merriam Webster Dictionary.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isoperimetric)

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking for this.